# How do you match all processes ending with .exe with a regex in linux/bash?

Tags: regex, linux, bash

Hey i'm trying to kill all processes ending with .exe using pkill in linux but it doesn't seem to work with case insensitive commands. This is the regexp i got so far. `.*[\.](?i)exe`

However bash returns syntax error near unexpected token '('

any suggestions?

Comment: How exactly do you call `pkill`? In particular, is the regex properly quoted (with single quotes)?

Comment: Do you have processes that end with `.exe` and `.EXE` that you are trying to match? Does `pkill *.exe` not do what you want or `pkill *.(exe|EXE)`?

Answer (score 2):

Just use `-i` flag for ignore case matching:

```
pkill -i -f '.*\.exe$'
```

**Note:** It seems `-i` is only available on BSD pkill

On other systems use this regex:

```
pkill -f '.*\.[eE][xX][eE]$'
```

Comment: I have it available on OSX but let me check man page of `gnu pkill` also

Comment: There is no such flag on linux afaik, the other regexp works but that is a little bit inconvenient imho

Comment: @thoggy: Yes unfortunately `-i` is available only on `BSD pkill`

Comment: So I'll take it that bash regexps doesn't support case insensitive then

Comment: This regex is not interpreted in BASH, it is processed in `pgrep/pkill` and it seems only BSD folks enabled `-i` flag. For other systems either use the command I showed above or use `kill $(ps ax | grep -i exe | awk '{ print $1 }')`

Comment: It simply wasn't the answer I wanted. Using [xX] for every letter if I want to match a word in not a optimal solution imo

Comment: I was talking about the alternate answer I provided in comments above using ps, grep and awk. If you have come up with some more optimal answer using `pkill` please post.